# Multiple commands with args under 1 hotkey in Sublime Text 3

Tags: json, sublimetext3, key-bindings, hotkeys, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to configure ST3 keybindings to reindent whole text, save file and refresh the browser on `ctrl+s`. I'm using Chain of Command and Browser Refresh plugins, but the problem is I don't know how to pass commands with arguments, so that the reindent command would affect whole text instead of one line only. `"single_line" : false` seems to be ignored.

```
"keys": ["ctrl+3"], 
    "command": "chain", 
    "args": {
        "commands": [
        ["reindent",{"context": "window", "args": {"single_line": false}}],
        ["browser_refresh"]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made it.

```
"keys": ["ctrl+s"], 
    "command": "chain", 
    "args": {
        "commands": [
        ["reindent",{"single_line": false}],
        ["browser_refresh"]
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you found a solution. Thought I'd mention that you may run into issues in the future as the plugin runs everything as a window command. I cleaned up some work from a post on the ST forums and created a plugin. https://github.com/skuroda/ImprovedMacros. It doesn't do everything I want it to yet, but it supports running multiple commands, from a user specified context (window, view, or application).